# php telegram sendAudio

Tags: php, audio, telegram, telegram-bot

I have a problem with sendAudio() function in php telegram bot.

```
if (strtoupper($text) == "MUSIC") {
$voice = curl_file_create('audio.ogg');
$content = array('chat_id' => $chat_id, 'audio' => $voice);
$telegram->sendAudio($content);
}
```

This don't work with an audio lenghtof 9 or more seconds. I also tried with .mp3 but nothing. Same function with an audio lenght of 6 or less seconds works. I looked in the documentation and it says only 50MB files are restricted. Help pls.
Here's my $telegram.

```
include("Telegram.php");
$bot_id = "xxxxxxx:yyyyyyyy_mytoken";
$telegram = new Telegram($bot_id);
```

And here Telegram.php:

```
class Telegram {
private $bot_id = "mytoken";
private $data = array();
private $updates = array();
public function __construct($bot_id) {
    $this->bot_id = $bot_id;
    $this->data = $this->getData();
}
public function endpoint($api, array $content, $post = true) {
    $url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' . $this->bot_id . '/' . $api;
    if ($post)
        $reply = $this->sendAPIRequest($url, $content);
    else
        $reply = $this->sendAPIRequest($url, array(), false);
    return json_decode($reply, true);
}
public function sendAudio(array $content) {
    return $this->endpoint("sendAudio", $content);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I am using this code to send mp3 audio file to telegram from my php application and It's working fine for me.

```
    $BOT_TOKEN = 'yourBotToken';
    $chat_id = '@yourChannel';
    $filePath = 'your/path/file';
    define('BOTAPI', 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' . $BOT_TOKEN . '/');
    $cfile = new CURLFile(realpath($filePath));
    $data = [
        'chat_id' => $chat_id,
        'audio' => $cfile,
        'caption' => $message
    ];
    $ch = curl_init(BOTAPI . 'sendAudio');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: how about download mp3 sounds in supergroups to my server?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use sendVoice for ogg file instead of sendAudio?

Answer (score 0):

Next code did work for me well:

```
<?php
exec( "curl -i -F 'chat_id=1234567890' -F 'voice=@audio.ogg' 'https://api.telegram.org/bot1234567890:AABBCCDDEEFFGGHH/sendVoice' 2>&1", $output , $return );
print_r( json_decode( end( $output ) ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code to send your audio file

function sendmessage($url, $post_params) {

```
$cu = curl_init();
curl_setopt($cu, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($cu, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_params);
curl_setopt($cu, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);   //get result
$result = curl_exec($cu);
curl_close($cu);
return $result;
}
$telsite = "https://api.telegram.org/bot"."$your_token_id";
$sendAudio_url = $telsite."sendAudio";
$post_parameters = array('chat_id' => $chat_user_id , 'audio' => $dir_of_audio);
sendmessage($sendAudio_url , $post_parameters);
```

Answer (score 0):

Example using [`westacks/telebot`](https://github.com/westacks/telebot) library:

```php
<?php

use WeStacks\TeleBot\TeleBot;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$bot = new TeleBot('123456:ABC-DEF1234ghIkl-zyx57W2v1u123ew11');

$bot->sendAudio([
    'chat_id' => 1111111111,
    'audio' => 'https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3'
]);

$bot->sendAudio([
    'chat_id' => 1111111111,
    'audio' => './path/to/local/file.mp3'
]);
```